# Get the class name from returned value of POST in Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have two dropdown lists and on selecting the data I used ajax to send it to a php file where I retrieved a table and send the whole table contents as per my query fields and I display it via

```
 jQuery("div#tablecontent").html(returnval);
```

But now i want to edit, delete the table view I displayed and I tried to get the class of the row I returned. But couldn't please guide me in how to get the class of the field I returned as whole table.
EDIT : Adding the code i ve done

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
jQuery("#select1").change(function(){
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo $base_url;?>?q=search/won",
    error: function(returnval) {
         alert("Failure");
    },
    success: function (returnval) {
        // alert(returnval);
         jQuery("select#fileds_content").html(returnval)
         //alert("Sucess"); 
    }
    })
    //
    jQuery("#fileds_content").change(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).val()){
            var datawon = jQuery(this).val();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo $base_url;?>?q=getbases/won",
                data:{ datawon : datawon},
                error: function(returnval) {

                    // alert(returnval);
                    // alert("Failure");
                },
                success: function (returnval) {
                    // alert(returnval);
                     jQuery("div#tablecontent").html(returnval);

                    //alert("Sucess"); 
                }
            })
```

Comment: so can you show us the code please?

Comment: seconded. codepen or jsfiddle would be wicked helpful.

Comment: You need .on (event delegation) to achieve that.

Comment: please have a look at the code... its simply getting the whole table from the php file as "returnval"

Comment: Which field do you want to access? Can you show the HTML of what `returnval` is returning?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you actually want to do, but from what I understood is that you cannot select a newly created element by its class. In that case, you cannot select a newly created elements because js does not know about it yet, thus, you can use something like [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/), this will make sure to run a function After an ajax call got completed.